# Knockout validation dont display default message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I would like to make KO validation work with the bootstrap styling for validation messages.

I have it so that the bootstrap validation message is displayed when the content is invalid but it also displays the OOB KO validation message alongside.

[image]

Below is my code, I was expecting that `data-bind="validationMessage: Name"` would stop the default from being displayed but this appears not to be the case. Is there something I am missing to stop this displaying?

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group" data-bind="css: { success: Name.isModified() && Name.isValid(), error: Name.isModified() && !Name.isValid() }">
        <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputName" placeholder="put something in and then clear" data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
            <span class="help-inline" data-bind="validationMessage: Name, visible: Name.isModified() && !Name.isValid()"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
       </form>
</div>
```

And

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable()
    .extend({ required: true });
    return self;
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/KmKa4/8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `data-bind="validationMessage: Name"` is not enough you need to set the `insertMessages` property to `false` to disable the automatic error message insertion.

You can do this when initializing the ko validation plugin with:

```
ko.validation.init({insertMessages: false});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4BWu/).

You can check out the other configuration options in the [Cofiguration documentation.](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: I'm trying to only show the message when the field is required - otherwise I need to move it. But it doesn't seem like it uses a new value of a ko.computed when it changes. Do you know if that is true?